# converter endereço em coordenadas google maps api

Tags: api, google-maps

Estou fazendo um site no qual uso Google Maps API pra fazer a rota dos ônibus e preciso converter o endereço capturado em um input em coordenadas, e exibir elas em um outro input pra ir acompanhando (estou fazendo isso com um alert de js e ta me deixando louco).

estou pegando as coordenadas juntas no seguinte código:

```
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                geocoder.geocode({'address':start}, function(results, status){
                    if( status = google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
                        latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
                        alert(latlng);
                    }
```

gostaria de pegar a lat e lng separadas em um input cada pra parar de usar o alert

Comment: uma sugestao. Use o console.log ao invés de alert rsrs

Comment: Vc quer passar o valor de latitude e longitude e passar para dois inputs?

Comment: sim, eu quero passar a latitude pra um input e a longitude pra outro, mas do jeito que está atualmente ele joga ambos em um alert :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O objeto "location" é uma instância da classe LatLng, [acesse a referência](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLng)

Logo, o código para buscar os campos de latitude e longitude separados fica:

```
document.getElementById('lat').value = latlng.lat();
document.getElementById('lng').value = latlng.lng();
```

Se seu objetivo é apenas debug, é mais simples usar a função console.log e observar o resultado no console do seu navegador.